# How to flag string if not in list

Tags: emacs, text-editor, string-parsing, aspell, flyspell

I'm interested in using Emacs (or similar) to rewrite documents in Simple English/Special English (two subsets of English that restrict themselves to simple words and grammar).

Ideally, as I'm typing, a string that is not in one of the defined sets would be flagged somehow.

I can do this easily for any *particular* string, or a whole document when I'm finished, but how can I automate this such that the text is being constantly checked and I can make changes on the fly? I can add a dictionary containing the words to `aspell` config, but it would replace the current `English` dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Windows, I'd suggest Notepad++ for this. You can create your own syntax highlighting and look-ahead. Any words used in list (or similar structure) can have a look-ahead/autocomplete functionality and any words not in that list can be flagged with a red underscore or something you define.